# How put mask on login with devise and save on DB just numbers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, mask

I have my login form, and my js mask, all ok. But where I put the code:

```
cpf.gsub!(/(\.|\-)/, "")
```

For mask work?

I need generate devise's controller for put on login or just model? I need User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  before_validation do
    self.cpf.gsub!(/(\.|\-)/, "")
  end
end
```

But it just work with registration user, dont login.
My login is this:

```
<div class="login">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><h4 class="cor-texto">AUTENTICAÇÃO DO USUÁRIO</h4></div>
    <div class="panel-body">
      <%= simple_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
      <div class="form-inputs">
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :cpf, required: false, autofocus: true, input_html: { class: 'form-control mascara-cpf' }, placeholder: 'LOGIN', label: false %>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <%= f.input :password, required: false, input_html: { class: 'form-control' }, placeholder: 'SENHA', label: false %>
        </div>
        <div class="espaco-check-box-login">
          <%= f.input :remember_me, label: 'Lembre-me', as: :boolean if devise_mapping.rememberable? %>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-actions">
        <%= f.button :submit, "Log in", :class => "btn btn-default btn-lg btn-block" %>
      </div>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My mask work into form, but save on DB with . and -, because this I cant sign in on system =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/Validations/Callbacks/ClassMethods/before_validation) out, it explains how `before_validation` works

> Defines a callback that will get called right before validation
>   happens.

It won't work because you're trying to do a POST request in a login action, which will not call the before_validation.

What I recommend you to do is unmask the value before the form gets submitted via js, or before the authentication method is called inside your controller.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A good way, according devise documentation is, override login query in your user.db like:

```
def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
     conditions = warden_conditions.dup
     if cpf = conditions.delete(:cpf)
          logger.debug cpf.gsub!(/[^\d]/, '')
          where(conditions).where(["cpf = :value", { :value => cpf }]).first
end
```